# React Native view not rendering in Android fragment

Tags: android, react-native

I have an android fragment, within which I'm trying to render a react view

```
class EmbeddedRnComponentFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentEmbeddedRnComponentBinding>() {

// some code

private fun populateComponentInReactView() {
    context?.apply {
        mReactDelegate = ReactDelegate(
            requireActivity(),
            (applicationContext as MainApplication).reactNativeHost,
            MAIN_COMPONENT_NAME,
            BasicReactComponentFragment.getLaunchOptions(getUri().build())
        )

        binding.hzReactRootView.apply {
            if (reactView != null) return
            reactView = ReactRootView(this.context).apply {
                startReactApplication(
                    (this.context.applicationContext as MainApplication).reactNativeHost.reactInstanceManager,
                    MAIN_COMPONENT_NAME,
                    BasicReactComponentFragment.getLaunchOptions(getUri().build())
                )
            }
            addView(reactView)
            requestLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

}

And my xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="adapter"
        type="xyz.RecyclerViewAdapter" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/home_background"
    android:padding="24dp">

    // some other views

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/hzReactRootView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:elevation="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my react component:

```
import React, {useCallback, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
import {animatedStyles4, scrollInterpolator4} from './animation';
import ReactNativeHapticFeedback from 'react-native-haptic-feedback';
import styles from './styles';
const RnComponentModule = NativeModules.RnComponentModule;

const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('screen').height;

const WheelPicker = (props: any) => {
  let list = JSON.parse(
    decodeURIComponent(props?.route?.params?.props?.props),
  );
  console.log("hzz props?.route?.params?.props?.props", props?.route?.params?.props?.props) // value is coming here, but rendering on UI.

  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
  const [carouselItems, setCarouselItems] = useState<any>(list);


  const options = {
    enableVibrateFallback: true,
    ignoreAndroidSystemSettings: false,
  };

  const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    console.log('item here', item)
    return (
        <View style={styles.textBody}>
            <Text style={styles.textTitle}>{ item.title }</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.carousalContainer}>
        <Carousel
          slideStyle={styles.carousalSlide}
          layout="default"
          ref={ref}
          data={list}
          itemHeight={screenHeight / 14}
          sliderHeight={screenHeight / 5}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          onSnapToItem={index => {
            console.log(list,"list here")
            setActiveIndex(index);
            ReactNativeHapticFeedback.trigger('soft', options);
            RnComponentModule.bridgeRnToAndroid(JSON.stringify(index))
          }}
          vertical={true}
          activeAnimationType={'timing'}
          slideInterpolatedStyle={animatedStyles4}
          scrollInterpolator={scrollInterpolator4}
          useScrollView={true}
          firstItem={carouselItems.length}
          loop={true}
          loopClonesPerSide={carouselItems.length}
          initialScrollIndex={carouselItems.length - 3}
          enableSnap={true}
          inactiveSlideScale={0.9}
          activeSlideAlignment={'center'}
          enableMomentum={true}
          decelerationRate={0.9}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.carousalOuterBody} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default WheelPicker;
```

The issue is that the initial render of the WheelPicker Props doesn't show on the UI.

Even when the data is hardcoded within the WheelPicker, the rendering is not happening, but the data is coming in the console of the RN component. Looks like lifecycle of React Native is not triggering.

Any help would be appreciated. (: